# how to create datatable with 6 fields for storing records regular 90 days

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

The website has more than 1000+ users. We want to store their day to day data in the database for next 90 days.Any query will be fine. Just want to know how to start this.
Thank you

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Comment: with more than `1000+ users` I assume you have a DB already in use?  which is it; MySQL or Oracle?  both are in your question's tags.

Comment: we have a website with more than 1000 users. they will enter their day to day activity what they did. let's assume we will give them 6 fields. users can enter record till 90 days. but every users have different days of starting and ending.

Comment: @NappingRabbit sorry its only MySQL, not an oracle. After reading your comment I remove that tag.

Comment: @NappingRabbit No bro, DB is not created yet. We have to create from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok well since reading your comments I wonder at your `6 field` limit.  Perhaps that is arbitrary?  I wonder that you are considering a row with a column for each user-entered record. I would suggest the following:

2 tables (for this functionality).  Let's call them `users`, and `recs`

In the `users` table you will store user info etc, but the most important is a primary key.  Using mysql that can and should be auto-incremented.

In the `recs` table you will store the inputted data from the users.  You will insert a new row for each saved record and a column in that table will refer to the primary key of the user's row in the `users` table.  Another column in this table will hold the time.  I personally like using a unix timestamp because it is an integer with fixed length and easily used everywhere, but it doesnt matter how you save the date/time.

You will set up some type of time-based checking system, maybe a cron job, or maybe a background process that runs when the page is loaded periodically.  This process will check for records in the `recs` table that were created before `(now - 90days)`.  You will delete those or flag them as invalid.

I am not sure how specific you wanted an answer to be, but that is the starting path I would use to accomplish what you are asking.  Since the number of rows is not predefined as the row width (columns) would be, the only reason to limit a user to 6 entries is choice.

if you were actually looking for syntax, I would suggest breaking that up into multiple specific questions; many have been answered already.